# Stop rotating when select the game object by mouse input

Tags: c#, unity

I am new to Unity and I am confused about how to solve this problem. Initially, I want to make a platform rotate to its center vector up like this.

```
transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Then, I want to stop it from rotating when the mouse select it, like:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;
if(Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)){
  //find a way to stop rotate
}
```

I cannot figure out how to stop it from rotating. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use [OnMouseDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) message to do so.

What you have to do is to make sure that your platform have any collider attached. Now implement `OnMouseDown` with the help of a flag. Like,

```
bool _shouldRotate = true;

void Update()
{
    if (_shouldRotate)
        transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (_shouldRotate)
        _shouldRotate = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add a tag to the platform object eg. "platform", then in the script where you are rotating the object make sure it checks if certain Boolean eg. **ROT** is true, then in the raycast from mouse script check the tag of the object like this: `if(hit.collider.tag == "platform")`

If it is then set the Boolean **ROT** to false which will prevent the line rotating the platform from running.